# ¿Cómo generar un proyecto con CMake?

Tags: c, gtk, cmake

Estoy realizando un proyecto en C con GTK y Cairo utilizando CMake para generar el Makefile y su compilación, tengo ciertos problemas con CMake porque me está dando un error al tratar de compilar y no logro identificar dónde está, creo saber cuál es el problema (no enlaza GTK+) ya que se queja que no encuentra *gtk/gtk.h* el cual se encuentra en mi cabecera gui.h. Mi árbol de directorios es el siguiente:

```
Proyecto
|--CMakeLists.txt
|--includes
|  |--GUI
|     |--gui.h
|     |--Principal
|        |--window-principal.h    
|--src
   |--main.c
   |--CMakeLists.txt
   |--GUI
      |--CMakeLists.txt
      |--gui.c
      |--Principal
         |--CMakeLists.txt
         |--windows-principal.c
```

Mi Proyecto posee dos directorios: *includes* y *src*, que, como sus nombres lo indican, uno es para las cabeceras y el otro para las fuentes.

Dentro de *src* se encuentra hasta el momento el directorio *GUI*, tengo separado mi proyecto de esta manera porque el diseño GUI va a ser bastante extenso, dentro de el por ahora solo se encuentra el directorio *Principal*, quiero separar cada parte de la GUI para un futuro mantenimiento, dejando un directorio para la estructura *Principal* de la GUI, abra otros directorios para el diseño de *Menú*, *Preferencias*, *Configuraciones*, *Cairo* etc, y todo será una sección diferente dentro del directorio *GUI*.

En el directorio *src* habrá otros directorios para todo lo correspondiente a el *Núcleo* del proyecto para así separar mi proyecto de la GUI para a futuro si deseo implementar una GUI en QT o llevarlo a Windows pueda hacerlo sin mucho trabajo, y no solo con la GUI, también si deseo cambiar a Cairo por OpenGL o Vulkan pueda hacerlo sin romper nada.

Mis archivos CMake son los siguientes:

**Proyecto/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(Proyecto)

include_directories(includes)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

**src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(Proyecto)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../includes)
add_subdirectory(GUI)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.c" GUI)
```

**GUI/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(INCLUDE_GUI ../../includes/GUI)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../../includes/GUI)
set(GUI_SOURCES
    gui.c
    ${INCLUDE_GUI}/gui.h
)

add_library(GUI ${GUI_SOURCES})
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GTK REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)
target_link_libraries(GUI PUBLIC ${GTK_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(GUI PUBLIC ${GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compile_options(GUI PUBLIC ${GTK_CFLAGS_OTHERS})

add_subdirectory(Principal)
```

En este CMakeLists.txt creo que está el problema, pero según la [documentación de CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html), el paquete [PkgConfig](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindPkgConfig.html?highlight=pkgconfig) debería enlazarlo ya que para mí está bien.

**Principal/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(WINDOW_PRINCIPAL_INCLUDE ../../../includes/GUI/Principal)
set(WINDOW_PRINCIPAL_SOURCE
    window-principal.c
    ${WINDOW_PRINCIPAL_INCLUDE}/window-principal.h)

add_library(WINDOW_PRINCIPAL ${WINDOW_PRINCIPAL_SOURCE})
target_link_libraries(WINDOW_PRINCIPAL PUBLIC GUI)
```

Antes tenia los CMake bien hechos porque me creaba el Makefile y me compilaba correctamente, pero lo "rompí" tratando de agregar este último, porque como pueden ver, dentro del directorio *GUI* todas su secciones deben tener enlazado GTK+ que este a su vez esta enlazado a librería que se crea en el directorio *GUI*.

Hay que tener en cuenta que GTK+ solo lo necesito enlazado a la librería que salga del directorio *GUI* porque en el resto de proyecto y sus respectivas secciones no lo necesito.

Así que no logro enlazar la librería GTK+ correctamente ni he podido lograr ese directorio seccionado que deseo.

Agradezco sinceramente sus respuestas, correcciones, inquietudes y consejos.

---

**EDITADO 1**

CMake genera el Makefile sin ningún contratiempo, pero al tratar compilar se queja que no encuentra la cabecera *gtk/gtk.h* que se encuentra dentro de la cabecera gui.h, el error es el siguiente:

> GUI/gui.h:7: error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
>    #include `<gtk/gtk.h>`

---

**EDITADO 2**

En el caché de CMake las dos variables **GTK_INCLUDEDIR:INTERNAL** y  **GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS** poseen las siguientes configuraciones:

```
GTK_INCLUDEDIR:INTERNAL=/usr/include

GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS:INTERNAL=/usr/include/gtk-3.0;/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0;/usr
/include/at-spi-2.0;/usr/include/dbus-1.0;/usr/lib64/dbus-1.0/include;/usr/inclu
de/gtk-3.0;/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/;/usr/include/cairo;/usr/include/pango-1.0;
/usr/include/harfbuzz;/usr/include/pango-1.0;/usr/include/atk-1.0;/usr/include/c
airo;/usr/include/pixman-1;/usr/include/freetype2;/usr/include/libdrm;/usr/inclu
de/libpng16;/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0;/usr/include/libpng16;/usr/include/glib-
2.0;/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include
```

Como dependencias muestra:

```
GUI_LIB_DEPENDS:STATIC=general;gtk-3;general;gdk-3;general;
pangocairo-1.0;general;pango-1.0;general;atk-1.0;general;cairo-gobject;
general;cairo;general;gdk_pixbuf-2.0;general;gio-2.0;general;gobject-
2.0;general;glib-2.0;
```

El compilador de C trata de compilar con la siguiente línea:

```
/usr/bin/cc  -I/home/usuario/Documentos/Programacion/GTK/Proyecto/includes   -o CMakeFiles/Proyecto.dir/main.c.o   -c /home/usuario/Documentos/Programacion/GTK/Proyecto/src/main.c
```

Comment: ¿podrias editar tu pregunta y agregar la salida de cmake para poder localizar el problema exacto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Después de un rato parado en este problema di con el causante, y es mas que todo una falta de conocimiento general sobre cmake, así que paso a responder la pregunta por partes, la primera parte es lo que dice el titulo de la pregunta, **Como generar un proyecto en cmake**, asi que basado en una serie de preguntas en la comunidad *StackOverflow(en ingles)* las cuales tienen mas de un par de años, pero al ser teoría y funcionamiento lógico, son perfectamente funcionales aún.

Lo siguiente es una traducción, resumen y conclusiones propias basadas en la respuesta a la pregunta [how is cmake used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007566/how-is-cmake-used), y la [documentación](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/index.html) de cmake.

## Que es CMake?


Su [página oficial](https://cmake.org/) dice:

> CMake es una familia de herramientas de código abierto y multiplataforma diseñada para desarrollar, probar y empaquetar software. CMake se utiliza para controlar el proceso de compilación del software utilizando plataformas sencillas y archivos de configuración independientes al compilador, genera makefiles y espacios de trabajo nativos que se pueden usar en el entorno de compilación de su elección. El conjunto de herramientas CMake fue creado por Kitware en respuesta a la necesidad de un entorno de construcción potente y multiplataforma para proyectos de código abierto como ITK y VTK.

CMake no compila, genera la configuración y los archivos de compilación, crea el o los Makefiles y *make* pasa a compilar(en linux) de pendiendo de la configuración que se genero, el scripts principal utilizado por CMake se llama **siempre** CMakeLists.txt, en este se encuentra TODO lo necesario para la compilación, que compilador se usara, que librerías se enlazaran al proyecto, que librerías se crearan, de que manera(Estáticas, compartidas o módulos), cómo esta seccionado el árbol de directorios del proyecto, configuraciones externas como por ejemplo que dicho proyecto se puede compilar utilizando Qt o GTK, etc.

En CMake se tiene una sola configuración general sin necesidad de tener varias configuraciones separadas dependiendo de con que compilador se trabaje, ademas es soportado por varios IDE como *Visual Studio*, *Qt Creator*, *Eclipse*, *Netbeans*, *Code::Blocks* etc. pudiendo pasar proyectos de IDE a IDE sin necesidad de cambiar nada, ya la configuración va en los archivos CMake.

## De que manera trabaja CMake?


Utilizare como ejemplo el árbol de directorios inicial de mi proyecto

```
Proyecto
|--CMakeLists.txt <== Primer CMakeLists.txt
|--includes
|  |--GUI
|     |--gui.h
|     |--Principal
|        |--window-principal.h    
|--src
   |--main.c
   |--CMakeLists.txt
   |--GUI
      |--CMakeLists.txt
      |--gui.c
      |--Principal
         |--CMakeLists.txt
         |--windows-principal.c
```

Su proyecto *CMake* se configura de acuerdo al primer *CMakeLists.txt* y ejecuta toda las instrucciones y configuraciones que se encuentren en este, un proyecto puede tener multitud de sub-directorios y como se puede notar en el árbol de directorios hay varios *CMakeLists.txt* en los diferentes sub-directorios, se ejecuta el primer CMakeLists.txt y dentro de este se encuentra una instrucción llamada [add_subdirectory(directorio)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_subdirectory.html?highlight=add_subdirectory) la cual especifica un sub-directorio en el que se encuentra otro script CMakeLists.txt, ejecutándolo, de esta manera se puede tener una estructura de directorios muy seccionada y bien organizada.

CMake realiza la configuración y compilación desde una carpeta que no es la raíz del proyecto, esto se llama [Compilación fuera de la fuente](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Out-of-source_build_trees), la cual tiene como beneficio mantener el orden del árbol del proyecto, porque los archivos generados quedan fuera de este, o pudiendo compilar varias versiones del mismo proyecto, una versión Release y otra Debug, como otros beneficios a partes. El árbol generado por CMake del proyecto se vería de la siguiente manera(sacando varios archivos generados que no pasare a explicar ahora):

```
Proyecto
├── CMakeCache.txt
├── cmake_install.cmake
├── Makefile
└── src
    ├── cmake_install.cmake
    ├── GUI
    │   ├── cmake_install.cmake
    │   ├── Makefile
    │   └── Principal
    │       ├── cmake_install.cmake
    │       └── Makefile
    └── Makefile
```

y al realizar un `make` al proyecto se genera el siguiente árbol siguiendo la configuración asignada:

```
Proyecto
├── CableadoEstructurado.cbp
├── CMakeCache.txt
├── cmake_install.cmake
└── src
    ├── Proyecto(Ejecutable)
    ├── CableadoEstructurado.cbp
    ├── CMakeFiles
    │   ├── Proyecto.dir
    │   │   └── main.c.o
    │   └── SRC.dir
    ├── cmake_install.cmake
    └── GUI
        ├── cmake_install.cmake
        ├── libA_GUI.a
        ├── libGUI.a
        └── Principal
            ├── cmake_install.cmake
            └── libWINDOW_PRINCIPAL.a
```

El proyecto esta construido y el ejecutable esta listo. Se puede cambiar el lugar del ejecutable o tener varios ejecutables, todo varia según su diseño de proyecto.

## Como construir un proyecto con CMake

 
El primer CMakeLists.txt del proyecto es el siguiente:

**Proyecto/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(Proyecto)

set(HEADER ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/includes)    
include_directories(includes)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

En la primera línea se establece la versión mínima requerida de *CMake*, esto siempre debe establecerse, en este caso es la versión 3.8 en la cual se tiene seguridad que funciona. El nombre del proyecto se establece con `project` y es aconsejable que se agregue, no es raro los casos donde se administra varios proyectos desde archivos en común, [SET](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/set.html?highlight=set) establece una variable normal, de cache o de entorno, en este caso se crea una propia utilizando la variable [CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-variables.7.html) para que guarde el lugar donde se tienen las cabeceras, [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/include_directories.html?highlight=include_directories) agrega los directorios donde el compilador buscara las cabeceras y por ultimo `add_subdirectory` pasaría a ejecutar el CMakeLists.txt dentro del directorio src.

Dentro del directorio *src* se encuentra otro script, es el siguiente:

**src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_subdirectory(GUI)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.c")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall --std=c11")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC A_GUI)
```

En este script se llama al script en *GUI*, y se crea el ejecutable con [add_executable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_executable.html?highlight=add_executable) de unos archivos fuentes(main.c) y por ultimo [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_link_libraries.html?highlight=target_link_libraries) se utiliza para vincular una biblioteca o indicador con un objeto determinado o **depedencias**, en resumen se indica que el objeto ejecutable tiene como dependencia a la libreria A_GUI, la cual se crea en el directorio GUI.

En el directorio GUI se encuentra el siguiente script:

**GUI/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(GUI_SOURCES
    gui.c ${HEADER}/GUI/gui.h    
    )

add_library(A_GUI STATIC ${GUI_SOURCES})

add_subdirectory(Principal)

include(FindPkgConfig)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GTK REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)
target_link_libraries(A_GUI ${GTK_LIBRARIES} WINDOW_PRINCIPAL)
target_include_directories(A_GUI PUBLIC ${GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compile_options(A_GUI PUBLIC ${GTK_CFLAGS_OTHERS})
```

En este script se crea la librería estática *A_GUI* con [add_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_library.html?highlight=add_library), esta librería es la que depende el ejecutable, la línea `include` agrega el paquete [FindPkgConfig](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindPkgConfig.html?highlight=findpkgconfig) el cual es *PkgConfig* que se agrega su modulo con `find_package`, `pkg_search_module` busca en el sistema a GTK+, `target_link_libraries`  enlaza la librería de GTK+ al proyecto, poniéndolo como dependencia de la librería *A_GUI* junto con la librería *WINDOW_PRINCIPAL*, la cual se crea en el sub-directorio *Principal*.

Esto es una muy pequeña vista de lo que puede hacer CMake y de que manera lo hace, pudiendo generar proyectos realmente complejos, y que pueden ser construidos en diferentes compiladores utilizando los mismos archivos cmake.

---

## Solución del problema

Esa fue una pequeña explicación de como funciona CMake, poniendo de ejemplo el proyecto en el que trabajo, ahora respondiendo a la duda por la cual cree esta pregunta en primer lugar, por qué mi configuración inicial no me funcionaba, no me enlazaba la librería GTK+ como dependencia de *A_GUI* y del proyecto.

Como el usuario Trauma había comentado poseía un problema de rutas, no me estaba agregando la ruta de las cabeceras GTK+, pero a su vez no se estaba poniendo como dependencia la librería A_GUI en el ejecutable.

Se agrego las siguientes líneas en los script's:

**src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC A_GUI)
```

**GUI/CMakeLists.txt**

```
target_link_libraries(A_GUI ${GTK_LIBRARIES} WINDOW_PRINCIPAL)
```

Realice unos cambios en los scripts(si son observadores ya se abran dado cuenta), el cual fue para hacerlos mas "elegantes", aunque el por qué de no funcionar era básicamente esas dos líneas.

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate bien en el mensaje de error:

> GUI/gui.h:7: error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory #include <gtk/gtk.h>

Se queja de que no encuentra un archivo *include*. Y ahora, en la parte relevante de tu `CMakeLists.txt`:

> target_include_directories(GUI PUBLIC ${GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})

El problema está claro. Ya estás colocando la ruta principal de las cabeceras GTK en la lista de directorios en los que buscar los *includes*.

Por lo tanto, tu `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` es incorrecto. Tal y como lo tienes puesto, el directorio `gtk` **ya está en la lista de directorios** en los que buscar las cabeceras.

Simplemente, elimina la parte del directorio:

```
#include <gtk.h>
```

Comment: nada, ya lo probé y reporta exactamente el mismo error.

Comment: @MarioFernando En el directorio en el que haces el *build*, mira en la caché de `cmake` el valor de GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS. Adicionalmente, si estás usando el `make` de GNU, puedes hacer `make VERBOSE=1` y observa la orden exacta que se está invocando `gcc ... -Ialgo`. Añádelo todo a la pregunta, porque a mi juicio, tienes un problema de rutas. Añade también lo que te devuelve `pkg-config  gtk+-3.0 --cflags-only-I`.